# For how many $n \in \{ 1 , 2 , \dots , 580 \}$ is $n$ a multiple of one or more of $4$, $6$ or $8$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inclusion-exclusion

So I believe I want to find the number of integers in the list divisible by 4,6,8
and then subtract the times I double counted the ones which are divisible by more then one.

But I'm not sure how I know how many are divisible by 4,6,8
?

Comment: Hint : inclusion-exclusion principle

Comment: Hint: LCM and Euler Totient function

Comment: Common sense: Only even numbers count.  All multiples of $4$ count.  So that's $\frac 14\cdot 580=145$ that count.  As well are the single mulptiles of $2$ that are also multiples of $6$.  There are $145$ even numbers that aren't multiples of $4$ and $\frac 13$ of them are multiples of $6$.  And three $[\frac 13\times 145]=48$ such numbers.  Plus the $145$ that are multiple of $4$.  Thats $145 + 48=193$... Or you could set up inclusion/exclusion carefully.

Answer (score 1):

Three hints:

1. Number of multiples of $k$ in $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$ is $\lfloor\frac{n}{k} \rfloor$
2. $|A \cup B \cup C| = |A|+|B|+|C|-|A \cap B|-|A \cap C|-|B \cap C|+|A \cap B \cap C|$
3. Set $A$, $B$ and $C$ will be the sets of multiples of $4$, $6$ and $8$ respectively

Comment: Hint 4) the intersection of the set of mulitples of $k$ and thes set of multiples of $m$ are the set of numbers that are multiples of both $k$ and $m$ and those are the set of numbers of multiples of the lowest commen mulitple of $k$ and $m$.  (That a hint for figuring what $|A\cap B|, |B\cap C|, |A\cap C|$ and $|A\cap B\cap C|$ are.